# How to call MVC controller action of a project from view of web API project?

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Project 1 is called `DemoMVCProj.proj`. Its main files are `index.html` and `DemoController`.

```
class DemoController : Controller {
// ----index action here----
    [HttpPost] public ActionResult CallAction()
    {
        // --some logic here--
        // --return action result--
    }
}
```

There is another project called `DemoMVCWebApiProj.proj`, where more than one web API is created.

There is a third project called `DemoUI.proj`, which is an AngularJS project for creating views.

`ApiController`s are called under this project using `DataFactory`s.

How can I call `DemoController` (from the `DemoMVCProj` project) from one of the view in the `DemoUI` project?

Comment: What do you mean by "call the controller"?  Do you just want to direct the user with a link?  It would be a link like any other link in HTML.  You'd use the URL for where you want to send the user.

Comment: @Tieson Thanks for the response. To explain you more on the problem what I am facing,

DemoMVCProj.proj (project1) => is a third party application built in .Net MVC and AngularJS.

DemoUI.proj and DemoMVCWebApiProj.proj are my application. I can run these two project has one application(Application1), so no problem in deployment but when it comes to DemoMVCProj.proj(third party application) code I have to run separately(Application2).

Main problem is, If running Application1 and Application2 separately then I need to buy two domain, which I don't want to do. 

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since DemoUI sounds like it's angular based, you would use $http to do any call's
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

If your routing is normal, you would use the url of /controller/action

If you simply wanna go to a view in the MVC proj without ajax loading, simply write an  tag with a href="/controller/action"